# develop IVR in java for send real time fax over internet protocol(FOIP)

Tags: java, fax, ivr

I want to develop IVR,so that have the ability to send real time fax in java,on ip protocol.
Where should I start?
Is also it  possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look to [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) project. Extended logic and functionalities can be implemented using Java or other languages via [AGI interface](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI).

There are several libraries implementing AGI also in Java (for example http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html)

Also take a look to [Noojee Fax](http://noojee.com.au/products/noojee-fax/fax-overview/) project

Comment: Do you know complete sample in asterisk-java?

Comment: No, but I think you can find it easily googlin' a bit